# Create PostGIS-Topology (edges, nodes, faces) from a list of edges

Tags: postgis, topology

I have a large in memory table of edges with the following structure:

```
facenr1, facenr2, x1, y1, x2, y2
```

`x1,y1` to `x2,y2` is a line.
`facenr1` and `facenr2` is the facenumber of the left and right face.

Now I want to load this into a PostGIS-Topology scheme, so that I create a correct topology and eventually get the faces in the faces table.

The documentation states that I can create this using INSERTs:

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgisTopology#LoadingTopologydata

How do I do this?